# Azure Data factory v2 copy activity source value is null sink value is not allowed null

Tags: azure, type-conversion, azure-data-factory

My question is about how/where to perform the type conversion during copy activity.

I have an Azure data factory pipeline which defines data imports from a TSV file in Data Lake Gen1 to SQL server database table.

The schema of the TSV file is: `{QueryDate,Count1,Count2}`

count1 and count2 may have no value.

example data in TSV file:

20180717    10

20180717    5   5

20180717    7   1

20180717        7

The Schema of the SQL server table is

```
{QueryDate(datetime2(7)), UserNumber(int), ActiveNumber(int)}
```

Both UserNumber and ActiveNumber have Not null constraint.

When I use copy activity in my pipeline to copy TSV data to the table I get an error like this:

> error Code": "2200", "message":
>   "'Type=System.InvalidOperationException, does not allow
>   DBNull.Value...

when count1 or count2 have no value I want to use 0 to replace the null value.
And I think that will not cause the error anymore.

But I don't know where and how to perform this conversion.

The conversion should in the source dataset, the sink dataset or the copy activity?

And the correct syntax of the conversion I don't figure out either.

I was trying to set the nullValue of the source datatset format setting
with value like null, 0, NULL, but none of them works, I still get the error.

```
"typeProperties": {
            "format": {
                "type": "TextFormat",
                "columnDelimiter": "\t",
                "nullValue": "NULL",
                "treatEmptyAsNull": true,
                "skipLineCount": 0,
                "firstRowAsHeader": false}, 
           ...
}
```

I also see the question: [Azure Data Factory - can't convert from "null" to datetime field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442230/azure-data-factory-cant-convert-from-null-to-datetime-field)

but it still not solve my problem.

Comment: I think maybe this expression @{coalesce(UserNumber,0)} will achieve the conversion, but still, I don't know where to place the expression.